# Is extra space allocated for variant records?

Tags: delphi, record

I'm working with the variant record below. The variable instance is Kro_Combi. SizeOf(Kro_Combi) reports 7812 bytes.  SizeOf(Kro_Combi.data) reports 7810 bytes. 
The sum of the SizeOf of all the other data structures composing the "non-directmode" case of the variant record also adds to 7810 bytes.

Why is there a two byte difference? I would like to have the two variant exactly overlay each other.

```
TKro_Combi = record
  case directmode:boolean of
    true : (
      data : array[0..7809] of byte
           );
    false : (
      Combi_Name            : array[0..23] of char;                //24
      Gap1                  : array[0..63] of byte;                // 24-87 (64)
      Ins_Effect_Group      : array[1..12] of TIns_Effect_Params;  //74 each,   (Ins_Effect_Data=9 bytes)  74*12 = 888
      Mast_Effect_Params    : array[0..229] of byte;               // 976-1205 : 230 bytes
      Vect_Aud__Drum_Params : array[0..97] of byte;                //1206-1303  : 98 bytes
      Karma_Common          : array[0..509] of byte;               //1304-1813 : 510 bytes
      Karma_Module          : array[0..3] of TKarma_Module;        //1814-2557 : 744 bytes each  Total span 1814 - 4789 = 2976 bytes total
      Common_Params         : array[0..11] of byte;                //4790-4801 = 12 bytes
      Timbre_Group          : array[1..16] of TTimbre_Params;   )  // 4802 -4989 = 188 bytes each,  16 Timbres, 4802-7809 = 3008 bytes total for all
  end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, there needs to be space for the `directmode` field. If you really want the record to have size 7810 bytes then you should remove that field. The other byte will be due to internal alignment and padding of the `false` part of the variant record. I can't yet quite work out where it comes from. No matter, you simply want to use a packed record to avoid any padding bytes.

```
TKro_Combi = packed record  
case boolean of
true : (
  data : array[0..7809] of byte
       );
false : (
  Combi_Name            : array[0..23] of char;                //24
  Gap1                  : array[0..63] of byte;                // 24-87 (64)
  Ins_Effect_Group      : array[1..12] of TIns_Effect_Params;  //74 each,   (Ins_Effect_Data=9 bytes)  74*12 = 888
  Mast_Effect_Params    : array[0..229] of byte;               // 976-1205 : 230 bytes
  Vect_Aud__Drum_Params : array[0..97] of byte;                //1206-1303  : 98 bytes
  Karma_Common          : array[0..509] of byte;               //1304-1813 : 510 bytes
  Karma_Module          : array[0..3] of TKarma_Module;        //1814-2557 : 744 bytes each  Total span 1814 - 4789 = 2976 bytes total
  Common_Params         : array[0..11] of byte;                //4790-4801 = 12 bytes
  Timbre_Group          : array[1..16] of TTimbre_Params;   )  // 4802 -4989 = 188 bytes each,  16 Timbres, 4802-7809 = 3008 bytes total for all
end;
```

Comment: That's it exactly - Thanks! I have no need for the directmode variable - I thought it was a necessary part of the declaration. I now remember the old "packed record" syntax.